docxtemplater in JS - how to add input data into output document from seperate pages?
I cannot get the input forms on my webpage to be added to the output of a word document. Instead of getting input values, I receive undefined, which is typical for docxtemplater script, when text inside document template, seperated by {}, e.g. in this case {NT_nr}, is not assigned a value, but is changed none the less to default value undefined. All other text in document is left unchanged.
There doesn't seem to be an issue on the frontend side - console.log(dataForm) retrieves the data upon submit click (on First_Output_Doc.jsx).
I have set up a ReactJS page with frontend and backend (Laravel framework) separated into separate categories (web and backend).
For backend I created server.js:
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const PizZip = require("pizzip");
const Docxtemplater = require("docxtemplater");

const app = express();
const port = 5000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.post("/generate-doc", (req, res) => {
    const {
        NT_nr,
        zemes_dalis,
        kvalifikacijos_pazymejimas,
        vertinimo_uzsakovas,
        patalpos_buto_nr,
    } = req.body;

    // Load the docx file as binary content
    const content = fs.readFileSync(
        path.resolve(__dirname, "./Template_Doc.docx"),
        "binary"
    );

    // Unzip the content of the file
    const zip = new PizZip(content);

    // Parse the template
    const doc = new Docxtemplater(zip, {
        paragraphLoop: true,
        linebreaks: true,
    });

    ////////// RENDER DATA FOR OUTPUT!
    doc.render(formData);

    // Generate the document as a buffer
    const buf = doc.getZip().generate({
        type: "nodebuffer",
        compression: "DEFLATE",
    });

    // Define the path where the file will be temporarily stored
    const outputPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "output.docx");

    // Write the buffer to the file
    fs.writeFileSync(outputPath, buf);

    // Send the file to the client
    res.download(outputPath, "output.docx", (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
        // Delete the file after sending it to the client
        fs.unlinkSync(outputPath);
    });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});

In App.js, I have setup:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import "./styles/App.css";
import "./styles/Footer.css";
import Home from "./components/Home.jsx";
import About from "./components/About.jsx";
import SignUp from "./components/SignUp.jsx";
import Login from "./components/Login.jsx";
import Footer from "./components/Footer.jsx";
import Background from "./components/Background.jsx";
import Missing from "./components/Missing.jsx";
import ContactForm from "./components/ContactForm.jsx";
import User_ProtectedRoute from "./utilities/User_ProtectedRoute.jsx";
import Admin_ProtectedRoute from "./utilities/Admin_ProtectedRoute.jsx";
import { FormProvider } from "./utilities/FormContext";
import First_Output_Doc from "./components/First_Output_Doc.jsx";
import Second_Output_Doc from "./components/Second_Output_Doc.jsx";
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="web">
        <Background />
        <FormProvider>
          <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
              <Route
                path="/about"
                element={<Admin_ProtectedRoute Cmp={About} />}
              />
              <Route path="/contact" element={<ContactForm />} />
              <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp />} />
              <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
              <Route
                path="/First"
                element={<User_ProtectedRoute Cmp={First_Output_Doc} />} // THE FIRST OUTPUT FORM
              />
              <Route
                path="/Second"
                element={<User_ProtectedRoute Cmp={Second_Output_Doc} />} // THE SECOND OUTPUT FORM
              />

              <Route path="*" element={<Missing />} />
            </Routes>
            <Footer />
          </BrowserRouter>
        </FormProvider>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

I have setup a FormContext.js file to manage the form data state across multiple pages:
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";

const FormContext = createContext();

export const FormProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    NT_nr: "",
    zemes_dalis: "",
    kvalifikacijos_pazymejimas: "",
    vertinimo_uzsakovas: "",
    patalpos_buto_nr: "",
    // Add other fields as needed
  });

  return (
    <FormContext.Provider value={{ formData, setFormData }}>
      {children}
    </FormContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default FormContext;

My first page for input document, First_Output_Doc:
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import '../styles/Output_Doc.css';
import Header from './Header';
import { TabTitle } from '../utilities/TabTitle';
import FormContext from '../utilities/FormContext';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function First_Output_Doc() {
  TabTitle("First output page");
  const { formData, setFormData } = useContext(FormContext);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
      const { name, value } = e.target;
      setFormData((prevData) => ({ ...prevData, [name]: value }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

      try {
          const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/generate-doc', formData, {
              responseType: 'blob',
          });

          // Create a URL for the blob and open it to download
          const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
          const link = document.createElement('a');
          link.href = url;
          link.setAttribute('download', 'output.docx');
          document.body.appendChild(link);
          link.click();
          link.remove();
      } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error generating document:', error);
      }
      console.log(formData);
  }

    return (
        <>
            <Header />
            <form className="container" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div className="page-title">
                    <div className="text">Dokumentui formatuoti</div>
                </div>
                <div className="underline" />
                <div className="inputs">
                    <div className="document-input-header">Nekilnojamo turto vertinimo Nr.</div>
                    <div className="input">
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name="NT_nr"
                            placeholder="Nekilnojamo turto vertinimo Nr."
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            value={formData.NT_nr || ''}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="document-input-header">Žemės dalis</div>
                    <div className="input">
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name="zemes_dalis"
                            placeholder="Žemės dalis"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            value={formData.zemes_dalis || ''}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="document-input-header">Kvalifikacijos pažymėjimas</div>
                    <div className="input">
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name="kvalifikacijos_pazymejimas"
                            placeholder="Kvalifikacijos pažymėjimas"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            value={formData.kvalifikacijos_pazymejimas || ''}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="submit-container">
                    <button className="submit" type="submit">Išvesti dokumentą (.DOCX)</button>
    <Link to="/second">
        <button className="submit">Go to Second Page</button>
    </Link>
</div>

            </form>
        </>
    );
}

export default First_Output_Doc;

My second page (for clarity sake)
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import '../styles/Output_Doc.css';
import Header from './Header';
import { TabTitle } from '../utilities/TabTitle';
import FormContext from '../utilities/FormContext';
import axios from 'axios';

function Second_Output_Doc() {
    TabTitle("Second output page");
    const { formData, setFormData } = useContext(FormContext);

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setFormData((prevData) => ({ ...prevData, [name]: value }));
    };

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        try {
            const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/generate-doc', formData, {
                responseType: 'blob',
            });

            // Create a URL for the blob and open it to download
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
            const link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = url;
            link.setAttribute('download', 'output.docx');
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
            link.remove();
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error generating document:', error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <>
            <Header />
            <form className="container" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div className="page-title">
                    <div className="text">Dokumentui formatuoti</div>
                </div>
                <div className="underline" />
                <div className="inputs">
                    <div className="document-input-header">Vertinimo uzsakovas</div>
                    <div className="input">
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name="Vertinimo uzsakovas"
                            placeholder="Vertinimo uzsakovas"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            value={formData.vertinimo_uzsakovas}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="inputs">
                    <div className="document-input-header">Patalpos buto nr</div>
                    <div className="input">
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name="patalpos_buto_nr"
                            placeholder="Patalpos buto nr"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            value={formData.patalpos_buto_nr}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="submit-container">
                    <button className="submit" type="submit">Išvesti dokumentą (.DOCX)</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </>
    );
}

export default Second_Output_Doc;

